# rails hash to javascriptjson list of parameters not?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ruby-on-rails-4, hash, datatables

I am trying to send a list of parameters from a Rails controller as a json response to an ajax call..

```
def build_json_data
  columns_array = []
  for heading in @headings do
    columns_array << { data: heading[:value]}.with_indifferent_access
  end
  @data = {columns: columns_array}.with_indifferent_access
end
```

t's received  as an array of Hash :

```
  @data[:columns] = [
     {"data"=>"Table"},
     {"data"=>"Owner"},
     {"data"=>"Statu"},
     {"data"=>"Origine"},
     {"data"=>"Source"},
     {"data"=>"Updated At"}
     ]
```

And I am trying to get it as :

```
  @data[:columns] = [
     {"data": "Table"},
     {"data": "Owner"},
     {"data": "Statu"},
     {"data": "Origine"},
     {"data": "Source"},
     {"data": "Updated At"}
     ]
     # this is what DataTables jQuery plugin wants a an array of column header
```

How can I send the correct array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm missing a bit of context here, but here goes:

```
@headings = [
  { value: "Table" },
  { value: "Owner" },
  { value: "Statu" },
  { value: "Origine" },
  { value: "Source" },
  { value: "Updated At" }
]

def build_json_data
  @headings.map { |heading| { data: heading[:value] } }.to_json
end
```

In this case, `build_json_data` will return your collection as JSON.  This should be suitable for return to the requesting client.  Here's the output as JSON:

```
"[{\"data\":\"Table\"},{\"data\":\"Owner\"},{\"data\":\"Statu\"},{\"data\":\"Origine\"},{\"data\":\"Source\"},{\"data\":\"Updated At\"}]"
```

If I'm missing something, please share a bit more context around what you're trying to do, and I'll be happy to help.

Comment: that's fine... your answer put me on the right way ... I can go to sleep now and enjoy a cool night